# How to cast a void pointer to a pointer when dereferencing?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, void-pointers

```
int x = 5;
int *xPtr = &x;
void **xPtrPtr = &xPtr;
printf("%d\n", *(int*)*xPtrPtr);
```

I have a void pointer pointing to an int pointer. What is the syntax for properly casting the void pointer when I want to dereference? The above code quits with:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int**’ to ‘void**’
```

Thank you!

Comment: can't you cast when assigning? -> void **xPtrPtr = (void)&xPtr;

Comment: Why are you casting? A bit more context would help in answering the question. Do you need the `void**` for an external function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For void pointers, you don't really need to know how many indirections there are.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void){
    int x = 5;
    int* pX = &x;
    void* pV = &pX;
    std::cout << "x = " << **(int**)pV << std::endl;
    // better use C++-Style casts from the beginning
    // or you'll be stuck with the lazyness of writing the C-versions:
    std::cout << "x = " << **reinterpret_cast<int**>(pV) << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Output:

```
x = 5
x = 5
```

[See this here](http://ideone.com/xHM2a).

Comment: Ah, shows my inexperience with C++.  Though I still say that if this is C++, you should use C++ constructs, casting included.  `**reinterpret_cast<int**>(pV)`

Comment: @Jeff: You are right, it's just the lazy me that always does C-Style casts, since the C++ versions are so verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer to int is `*((int **)xPtrPtr)`

Answer (score 0):

```
void **xPtrPtr = (void**)&xPtr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int x = 5;
    int *xPtr = &x;
    void **xPtrPtr = reinterpret_cast<void**>(&xPtr);
    int y = **reinterpret_cast<int**>(xPtrPtr);
    cout << y;
```

Compile:  No Error. No Warning!

Output:

```
5
```

Code at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/1nxWW

Comment: Thank you for showing me the concept of "reinterpret_cast". In the question mentioned above, the simplest answer is imho that I don't need to know the level of indirections when it comes to void pointers.

Comment: @Christian: I think that is a bad form to say it. What is true that a pointer to any object (including a pointer to a pointer, or a pointer to a pointer to a pointer etc.) can be stored in a void pointer and then can be converted back to the original pointer type. Note also that this is true only for pointer to objects (not for pointer to functions or pointer to members).

Answer (score 0):

This compiles correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int x = 57; 
   int *xPtr = &x; 
   void **xPtrPtr = (void**)&xPtr; 
   printf("%d\n", *((int*)*xPtrPtr));
}
```